# Customize Microsoft PowerToys URI

Tags: plugins, powertoys

I would like to use my own custom shorthand in the URI.

I would like to type in "/niv" and have PowerToys recognize it as "logosres:niv2011;ref=BibleNIV."

I could then add to the link with whatever I type in next. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you add another example of what you're looking for? It's not clear what `logosres:niv2011;ref=BibleNIV` is, or how it would execute - I assume you have a plugin? I'm pretty sure you cannot use a single slash `/` to start direct activations since it conflicts with the other path stuff. MS has a list here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/run

Comment: The provided URL is a link within a specific app, a virtual library. PowerToys recognizes it as a URL and opens the app to the specific book. By adding a number to the end of the string I can have it open to a specific page number.

I don't want to type in the long URL every time, I'd like to just type in a something like 'niv 100' and have PowerToys recognize it as 'logosres:niv2011;ref=BibleNIV.100'

Answer (score 0):

Powertoys just relies on windows for URL handling, like ms edge or chrome

You can create a new protocol handler for `NIV://` URLs with steps in the answers here: [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38205984/7411885)

And set the `command` to execute something like this. *It should look like the current one for* `logosres`, but with the book reference pre filled-in:

```
"C:\path\to\logosres.exe" "niv2011;ref=BibleNIV.%1"
```

Then you should be able to call stuff like `NIV:100` from powertoys and have it launch